# How to make working two different regex in one?

Tags: regex, flutter

I search to match date for a specific key, but currently I success to either match all date, or match my specific key but not with date separate.

Here is a more visual explication

in Input I have

```
Mystring ="
Text("List1:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2020-09-02 04:30, 2020-09-03 00:30, 2020-09-03 02:30, 2020-09-03 04:30, 2020-09-03 07:25, 2020-09-03 10:00, 2020-09-03 10:02],
Text("List2:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2020-09-02 04:30, 2020-09-03 00:30, 2020-09-03 02:30, 2020-09-03 04:30, 2020-09-03 07:25, 2020-09-03 10:00, 2020-09-03 10:02]
"
```

with this function, I match all date of Mystring

```
 RegExp regExp79 = new RegExp(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}');
 mylistdate = regExp79.allMatches(Mystring).map((z) => z.group(0));
 print(mylistdate);
```

But output take all date ( list1 and List2)
I try to match only list1

So I try to make character limitation. For example if I want only date from list1, I tried to match  `Text("List1:[`. and `]`

All these regex work separatly but don't found how to make work together

```
Text\("list1:\[    => start limitation
    
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}) => extraction of date 

(.*?)] => end of limitation
```

but if I melt all it's not work, it select only first date, I would match all date of the limited selection

```
Text\("List1:\[(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}).*?]
```

https://regex101.com/r/6adb1u/1

Comment: Flutter regex still does not support infinite length lookbehind patterns, right? If it did, you could just use JS regex like `/(?<=Text\("List1:\[[^\][]*?)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}(?=[^\][]*])/` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bd55uU/2))

Comment: Thank you !! Your are the man !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=Text\("List1:\[[^\][]*?)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}(?=[^\][]*])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bd55uU/3)

**Details**

- `(?<=Text\("List1:\[[^\][]*?)` - a positive lookbehind that requires `Text("List1:[` and then any 0 or more chars other than square brackets (as few as possible) immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}` - 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-`, 2 digits, a whitespace, 2 digits, `:` and 2 digits
- `(?=[^\][]*])` - a positive lookahead that requires any 0 or more chars other than square brackets (as many as possible) followed with a `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Code example:

```
String Mystring ="\nText(\"List1:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2020-09-02 04:30, 2020-09-03 00:30, 2020-09-03 02:30, 2020-09-03 04:30, 2020-09-03 07:25, 2020-09-03 10:00, 2020-09-03 10:02],\nText(\"List2:[2000-00-00 00:00, 2020-09-02 04:30, 2020-09-03 00:30, 2020-09-03 02:30, 2020-09-03 04:30, 2020-09-03 07:25, 2020-09-03 10:00, 2020-09-03 10:02]";
RegExp regExp79 = new RegExp(r'(?<=Text\("List1:\[[^\][]*?)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}(?=[^\][]*])');
print(regExp79.allMatches(Mystring).map((z) => z.group(0)).toList());
```

Output:

```
[2000-00-00 00:00, 2020-09-02 04:30, 2020-09-03 00:30, 2020-09-03 02:30, 2020-09-03 04:30, 2020-09-03 07:25, 2020-09-03 10:00, 2020-09-03 10:02]
```

Comment: Little question, If I have some date ( more than 5) I have in ouput  (2000-00-00 00:00, 2020-09-02 04:30, 2020-09-03 00:30, ..., 2020-09-03 10:00, 2020-09-03 10:02)

Comment: I don't understand why I have ,...,

Comment: That is just a display quirk, your list actually contains all the items. You may easily check that with `for (Match m in regExp79.allMatches(Mystring)) {
    print(m.group(0));
  }`

Comment: It's weird.. all data are well listed with your code, but when I print output i have ,.., and because of ,..., prefs.setStringList can't work and return null. But if I add manually in this format  mylistdate = ['2000-00-00 00:00','2020-09-02 04:30', '2020-09-03 00:30' ]; it's work